# Running Virtualbox 6.1.22 on Ubunti 21.04, I get 'Effective UID is not root' every time it try to start a VM

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 with the default Virtualbox that comes with Ubuntu. VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 6.1.22_Ubuntu r144080 .

It starts up fine, but when I try to start a VM, I get:

> ```
> Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000) (rc=-10)
> Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.
> where: SUPR3HardenedMain what: 2 VERR_PERMISSION_DENIED (-10) - Permission denied.
> ```

So, I tried reinstalling Virtualbox. No dice, I get the same error. So, I tried `sudo chown 4755 /usr/lib/virtualbox/Virtualbox`, but then I got the error saying that running as root was a no-no, due to security, which makes sense.

So, help? Any ideas?

Additional information, if I run on:

`sudo virtualbox` it seems to work fine.

More additional info:

I filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1935856) on this against Virtualbox on Ubuntu 21.04.  It is now confirmed.  No ETA on a fix.

Comment: can you show  `ls -al /usr/lib/virtualbox/` Maye some stickybit are not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer from someone via email, through the bug I entered on Launchpad.

The answer is:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBoxVM
```

Comment: Yeah that I was after.